# Gentoo: Install a separate newer version of python without upgrading the os or the current python version

Tags: python, gentoo

Currently I have python version 2.5.2

When I run this command:

```
emerge -a python:2.7
```

I get this message

```
Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds to satisfy "dev-lang/python:2.7".
```

Could you please tell me what is the best way to proceed to be able to use python 2.7 and keeping the current version as well?

Thank you

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Gentoo, but it appears they [discontinued](https://archives.gentoo.org/gentoo-dev/message/fccd00811f67f0e8bf8022849200f70a) support for 2.5 over 2 years ago. Can you explain why your system is so out of date and what steps you will take to rectify this? This question is unanswerable without that context.

Comment: The reason is that we have some huge legacy code in python 2.5 that we cannot afford to migrate because we do not have enough resources at this moment.

Comment: Again, I'm an outsider to Gentoo, having not used it in almost six years, but it seems to me that you need to read up on the news posts for the last two years and slowly, carefully bring your whole system up to date. I doubt there's a solution for any Linux like Gentoo that doesn't involve bringing your whole system into modernity, since Python 2.5 is long deprecated and 2.7 (your upgrade target) is 'current stable'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your biggest issue is that the current portage tree does not contain a 2.5 package, and I suspect it's telling you 2.7 doesn't exist because you have not updated your tree (`emerge --sync`) in a long time. Any Python2 update you do will want to migrate you away from 2.5 and to 2.7. To maintain 2.5 as a portage supported atom, you would need to enable an overlay that supports it. A quick search found that the **dberkholz** and **embedded-cross** overlays might be a good place to start. At least at one time, they included python-2.5. You will need to use layman ([Layman Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/)) to get these.

A better alternative might be to do an update (which should give you 2.7), and then install 2.5 manually. You will need to manage your environment properly, especially if your 2.5 modules are not command-line launched. A good place to start would be here: [Eselect dev guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Eselect/Developer_guide). That link will show you how to take your custom, non-supported build (python-2.5), and have the system recognize it. This way, you can keep your box current, keep your 2.5 python, and use eselect to do things the "proper way."

Either route you take, it sounds like you have your work cut out for you with such an old setup. Option #1 might be easier if you prefer not to make a large system update. Using layman to grab ebuilds not in the current portage tree may reduce the number of packages that need to be rebuilt.

Given the choice, I would recommend option #2. It gives you a more current system and seems the more proper approach.

Comment: Thank you for your insights